# How to call WCF methods that return custom object from Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

My silverlight application is connecting to a  WCF webservice method of the following contract. I am able to retrieve the`List<>` correctly using wcftestclient.exe.

```
[OperationContract]
List<CustomClass> GetCustomObjectsById(int uid);
```

However I am not sure how to call this from my silverlight client.

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client sc = new Service1Client();

sc.GetCustomObjectsByIdCompleted += new EventHandler<GetCustomObjectsByIdCompletedEventArgs>(sc_GetCustomObjectsByIdCompleted);

..
void sc_GetCustomObjectsByIdCompleted(object sender, GetCustomObjectsByIdCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      List<CustomClass> ac = (List<CustomClass>)e.Result[0]; //How to access here
}
```

EDIT: 
I am calling the service like this:

```
sc.GetCustomObjectsByIdAsync(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Result` property is the returned value from your contract.  In this case, you should be able to just use:

```
  List<CustomClass> ac = e.Result;
```

This also requires that your service reference is configured to return collections as `List<T>` instead of using Array - for details, refer to the [Configure Service Reference Dialog help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514724.aspx).  (WCF clients can use a different collection type than what is returned by the service, as they're "reconstructed" as the type gets deserialized on the client side...  By default, all methods that return collections will return an array or `Dictionary<T,U>` unless you choose to configure them to do otherwise.)

Note that you'll also need to start the operation sometime after subscribing to the completion event by calling `sc.GetCustomObjectsByIdAsync();`

Comment: Shouldn't I use the Async method?

Comment: @neutrino Yes - corrected.  Just a typo ;)  I added some other information, btw - I suspect the problem is that you have the service reference configured to return an array, not a `List<T>`...

Comment: I didn't quite understand it. I am already specifying the return type as `List<CustomClass>` in the operation contract and in `Service1.svc.cs` file. But I am getting compilation errors when I do `List<CustomClass> ac = e.Result;`

Comment: @neutrino In the *client*, open up Service References, and right click on the service reference and hit Configure.  In there, you'll see an option to specify the collection type.  It's probably set to Array - if so, change it to `List<T>`.  WCF can (and does!) use different collection types on the client than what is specified on the service in the operation contract...

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate the WCF Service call by calling method

```
sc.GetCustomObjectsByIdCompleted += new EventHandler<GetCustomObjectsByIdCompletedEventArgs>(sc_GetCustomObjectsByIdCompleted);
//call the WCF Service method Asynchronously and once the call is complete
// sc_GetCustomObjectsByIdCompleted method will be called with results
sc.GetCustomObjectsByIdAsync();
```

Comment: Am doing that. I am not sure about how to retrieve it in the `sc_GetCustomObjectsByIdCompleted` method